# How can we print and download mat-table as pdf

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am unable to download the angular material table as pdf.
Using the below code only a blank file is getting downloaded.
And can we print the mat-table

```
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

 print(){
    let doc = new jsPDF(); 
    doc.autoTable({
      head: [['NAme','approved','utilised', 'available','asd','sadadasada','asdas']],
      body: this.dataSource.filteredData //returning [["log1", "$100"], ["log2", "$200"]]
    });
    doc.save('table.pdf')
  }
```

Comment: Can you setup stackblitz demo for this?

Comment: which jspdf version you are using?

Comment: could you please provide full code?

Comment: got resolved used columns attribute inside doc.autoTable which assigned my variable names o the data coming from dataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  was facing a similar issue like this so I went through jspdf-autotable npm documentation there I realised body requires array of arrays for which I was passing array of objects, just check if you are not making the same mistake.

To convert array of arrays you can use the following

```js
let data = [];
const displayedColumns = ['NAme','approved','utilised', 'available','asd','sadadasada','asdas']

this.dataSource.forEach(obj => {
  let arr = [];
  this.displayedColumns.forEach(col => {
    arr.push(obj[col]);
  });
  data.push(arr);
});
```

Now we can simply pass this arrays of array to body of jsPDF object

If this problem had a similar issue then the solution will be as follows

```js
print(){
  let doc = new jsPDF(); 
  
let data = [];
const displayedColumns = ['NAme','approved','utilised', 'available','asd','sadadasada','asdas']

this.dataSource.filteredData.forEach(obj => {
  let arr = [];
  this.displayedColumns.forEach(col => {
    arr.push(obj[col]);
  });
  data.push(arr);
});      
  doc.autoTable({
    head: [['NAme','approved','utilised', 'available','asd','sadadasada','asdas']],
    body: data
  });
  doc.save('table.pdf')
}
```